# How to make android phone to visit my wordpress?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, android

There is a mini home wifi network in my home.The wireless router is `192.168.1.1`. Computer A is `192.168.1.2`, the wordpress was build on it. ALL the urls of my wordpress are the form of `mywp.com/wp/?m=201409`, there is a line in `/etc/hosts` of Computer A.

```
192.168.1.2   mywp.com
```

Computer B is `192.168.1.3`, there is a line in `/etc/hosts` of Computer B also.

```
192.168.1.2   mywp.com
```

Now the wordpress can be visited when to input `mywp.com/wp/?m=201409` in Firefox both on Computer A and B. My android phone IP is `192.168.1.4`, the wordpress can not be visited when to input `mywp.com/wp/?m=201409` in Android's Firefox.
How to set my Android phone to visit my wordpress?

How to parse the domain name `mywp.com` into `192.168.1.2` for my Android phone?
Which computer will the bind9 software be installed on? Computer A or Computer B? Anyone of them can be installed on?

Comment: Add `192.168.1.2 mywp.com` to the hosts file of the router.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your website, from the smartph'one, with this URL: http://192.168.1.2 /wp/?m=201409 Chances are high it will work and if not, things can be fixed easily on the webserver side.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is set up a private DNS server (or use a service like [OpenDNS](http:///www.opendns.com/)).  The difficulty of this can range from extremely simple to extremely complicated.  Google is your friend here, but check this out https://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/general/20110413/simplest-dns-server if you're up to messing around in Linux.

Answer (score -1):

When you type "xyz.com" into a browser it will do a DNS Lookup which checks the following places;

- Your browser's cache
- Your computer's `hosts` file and cache
- Any computers on your network advertising that computer name (eg "desktop.local")
- Any computers on the network which can answer DNS requests
- Your router's configuration and cache
- Public DNS servers (as configured on your machine or router)
- (plus more, probably!)

Editing your `hosts` file as you have done is the easiest way, and as you've discovered, is limited to the local machine. Sadly this is not something you can do on an Android phone unless you have rooted it (in which case there are apps which can). Public DNS isn't going to help because your web server is on the internal network.

Therefore I think your options are, in order of simplicity;

1. Configure your router, if you can, by setting up DNS masquerading or by editing `/etc/hosts`
2. Have your Windows computer advertise a computer name on the local network. Reconfigure the web server and Wordpress to serve on the computer name.
3. Set up a DNS server on your local network